# Calculate the rate of change of volume, $V$ (in $m^{3}$), of water in a tank

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$V=t^3-5t^2+6t+2$, where $t$ is the time in hours measured from a particular instant and $0 \leq t \leq 4$.

Find the rate of change of volume with respect to time after:

(i) $0.5$ hours

My attempt: $$\frac{dV}{dt} = 3t^2-10t+6$$
                 $$\text{When } t = 0.5,$$
          $$\frac{dV}{dt}\bigg\lvert_{t = .5} =3\cdot(0.5)^{2}-10\cdot(0.5)+6$$
$$\frac{dV}{dt}\bigg\lvert_{t = .5} = 1.75$$

(ii) $2$ hours

(iii) $3$ hours

Correct approach? Would I use the same method for the other times?

Comment: It seems good. And yes, here is the same method to use in the 3 cases (I don't see other simple methods).

Comment: Yes & Yes. What makes you think there's a problem?

Comment: I'm not very good at maths, i always second guess myself so i like to check just to be ssure :)